# rails 3.1 updating css issues

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I just updated from 3.0.8 to rails 3.1 rc1. However,the css in my site is clearly not being accessed beacuse my site has no design anymore. I though i could fix it by creating an assets folder and placing my stylesheets and js inside the app/assets folder but that hasn't worked.

I also commented this line out in my `config/environments/development.rb` file

```
#config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true
```

and I added this file to my `config/application.rb` file

```
    config.assets.enabled = true
```

Here is what my gemfile looks like:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0.rc1'

gem 'devise'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'rails3-generators' 
gem 'rails_admin', :git => 'git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git'
gem 'sass-rails'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby'
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. my images are also not showing up

Answer (score 0):

Your `app/assets` directory should look like this:

```
app/
    assets/
        images/
            pancakes.png
            ...
        javascripts/
            application.js
            ...
        stylesheets/
            application.css
            ...
```

There is [a guide to the new asset pipeline.](http://ryanbigg.com/guides/asset_pipeline.html) You might have to fix some paths as well.

Comment: is there a way where i can stay with rails 3.0.8 and use rails_admins version 3.0.8? right now when i try to install it,it won't let me because i have 3.0.8, but I installed it before with 3.0.8. Can i do like gem'rails_admin' -v 3.0.8?

Comment: @Jake: You'd need to now which version of rails_admin works with 3.0.8, then specify that particular version in your Gemfile.